# Using slider input values as variables

Tags: r, shiny

I'm new to Shiny and am still wrapping my mind around the syntax. I'm creating an app where I'd like to use the values of a range slider to crop a raster. However, I can't figure out how to integrate it outside of a render function.

For example, if I have a simple 10x10 raster, with values from 1:100, I'd like to keep only the range in the slider.  Doing this manually with set numbers, say 20-40, I'd run something like:

```
r<-raster(ncol = 10, nrow = 10)
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
plot(r)
r[r <= 20] <- NA
r[r >=40] <- NA
plot(r)
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to integrate the slider variables into this type of set up. I added the renderText to ensure I was referencing the values properly, but I can't figure out how to use these values outside of a rendering function.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("range","range:", min = 1, max = 100, value = c(10,50)),
  plotOutput("original"),
  textOutput("range"),
  plotOutput("cropped")
  )

server<- function(input, output){
  r<-raster(ncol = 10, nrow = 10)
  values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
  r2<-r
  reactive({r2[r2 <= input$range[1]] <- NA})
  reactive({r2[r2 >= input$range[2]] <- NA})
  output$original<- renderPlot(plot(r))
  output$cropped<- renderPlot(plot(r2))
  range <- reactive({cbind(input$range[1], input$range[2])})
  output$range<- renderText({range()})
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your variables r and r2 listening the changes in the slider you have to make it reactive:

```
library(raster)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("range","range:", min = 1, max = 100, value = c(10,50)),
  plotOutput("original"),
  textOutput("range"),
  plotOutput("cropped")
)

server<- function(input, output){

  r <- reactive({
    localVar <- raster(ncol = 10, nrow = 10)
    values(localVar) <- 1:ncell(localVar)
    # return
    localVar
  })
  r2 <- reactive({
    localVar <- r()
    localVar[localVar <= input$range[1]] <- NA
    localVar[localVar >= input$range[2]] <- NA
    # return
    localVar
  })
  output$original<- renderPlot(plot(r()))
  output$cropped<- renderPlot(plot(r2()))
  range <- reactive({cbind(input$range[1], input$range[2])})
  output$range<- renderText({range()})
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```